# Сбалансированное число

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, числа, лямбда-выражение

У меня есть задача.

> Написать функцию balanced_num, которая определяет является ли заданное
>   сбалансированным, т.е.
>   сумма цифр справа и слева от середины равны (abcde ==> a + b == d + e;
>   abcdef ==> a + b == e + f)
>   Примеры:
>   balanced_num(2222) ==> True balanced_num(135622) ==> True

Задача может показаться тривиальной , но я не могу понять имеет ли смысл приводить входные данные к строке и вводить анонимную функцию для разбиения чисел по группам для нахождения сумм ?

Comment: если не работать со строкой, то вычислять кол-во разрядов и брать остаток и частное от деления а потом все равно разбивать на разряды

Comment: Со строковыми данными, как ни странно, работать будет проще. Им в общем чхать на длину, тогда как арифметика длинных чисел может оказаться излишне затратной. Самой большой сложностью я вижу не вычисления, а проверку входных данных - в частности, проверку, что введённое число действительно является простым (кстати, с этой стороны примеры входных-выходных данных некорректны, ибо числа даны составные).

Comment: @Akina *проверку, что введённое число действительно является простым* - а зачем? А... из заголовка! Но в тексте об этом уже нет ничего :)

Comment: @splash58 См. сабж: "Сбалансированное **простое** число". А надо или нет - это уже к автору вопрос, где именно он налажал.

Comment: @Akina да, я уже поправил комент :)

Comment: Заголовок поправил, да действительно ошибка вышла, про простые речи не было )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, использовать лямбда функции для данной задачи неуместно, т.к. они получатся длинными и нечитаемыми.

Использовать обычные функции будет более целесообразно.

**Вариант решения с преобразованием числа в строку:**

```
def sum_of_digits(num):
    return sum(map(int, str(num)))

def is_balanced(num):
    num_str = str(num)
    mid_idx = len(num_str) // 2
    return (sum_of_digits(num_str[:mid_idx])
            == 
            sum_of_digits(num_str[mid_idx + len(num_str) % 2:]))
```

**Численный вариант решения:**

```
from math import log10, ceil

def sum_of_digits(num):
    res, n = 0, int(num)
    while n > 0:
        res += n % 10
        n //= 10
    return res

def is_balanced(num):
    num_len = ceil(log10(num))
    left_num = num // 10 ** (num_len // 2 + num_len % 2)
    right_num = num % ( 10 ** (num_len // 2))
    return (sum_of_digits(left_num)
            == 
            sum_of_digits(right_num))
```

Comment: Оба решения хорошие, но во-первых: как правильно указал @Akina,  могут возникнуть проблемы с арифметикой длинных чисел, во-вторых: как обрабатывать 0 ? Может возникнуть исключение с обработкой числа.